# DIVitis from React

Tags: html, reactjs, semantic-markup

I started working at a company who use REACT and I noticed that the HTML output has a TON of unnecessary divs. The developers tell me it's necessary for REACT, but I find it hard to believe that a modern framework/library/tool would force bad HTML practices on us. However, I can't seem to find any articles or references on this issue online. Is it really neccessary to wrap everything into a div? Why can't we wrap into the semantically correct element, like a p tag or nav, etc.? And finally, is this generally acceptable by the development community?

Answer (score 5):

You can use any valid HTML5 tag in React.js as long as you return single DOM Node from your component `render` method. This is the only requirement.

[List of supported tags and attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html)

Answer (score 1):

As the React documentation states:

> React components can only render a single root node. If you want to return multiple nodes they must be wrapped in a single root.

That is the only requirement React has. Doesnt matter if the root node (element) is a div, ul, li, p, span, and so on - as a matter of fact, the root node *should* be the correct element instead of meaningless divs.

**Sources:**

[React Docs on displaying data](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html)

We are developing a large React application in my company.

Comment: You could use `React.Fragment` instead of a div where you need a single root node..